# Create new Bitmap with zoomed content of existing Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to create a new Bitmap from an existing one that is just a zoomed version of the old one that is centered around the midpoint of the image.

What I currently have is

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(2,2);

resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(),
                        bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

But somehow this doesn't really work, the new bitmap looks just like the old one.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            File file = new File("/sdcard/"+imagename.png);  
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
```

or like that

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagearray , 0, imagearray .length);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```